# Split the integer evenly

Tags: java

I have an integer n, and I need to split that integer into 2 integers, as the sum of that 2 integers should equal to n.

For example n=12, I should like to have 4,8. as it should be 0+4=4, then 4+4=8, then 8+4=12. ie. the interval between the digits should be even, it is very important. N should be converted to split to evenly interval number. I have tried the following code, but sometimes it gives wrong answer.

```
int a = n/3;
int b = (n/3) * 2;
if(a+b==n)
{

}
else
{
    n=n+(n-(a+b));
    System.out.println("new n "+n);
    a = n/3;
    b = (n/3) * 2;      
}
```

Comment: What if you have an odd number, like 9? 0+9, 1+8, 2+7, 3+6, 4+5, all of these have odd intervals.

Comment: So you want your n to be split into three intervals of equal size?

Comment: @Manikandan and what should happen if n is not a multiple of 3? Increase it to the next multiple of three? Or find the nearest multiple of three?

Comment: @ isnot2bad, increase to next multiple of three

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code divides `n` into three equal intervals. If `n` is not a multiple of three, it is increased to the next greater multiple of three:

```
int a = n / 3;
if (a * 3 < n) {
    a++;
    n = a * 3;
}
int b = a * 2;
```

Your intervals are: `0 - a`, `a - b`, `b - n`

Answer (score 1):

> and what should happen if n is not a multiple of 3?
>
> increase to next multiple of three

This gives you two options

```
int a = (n+2) / 3; // round a up
int b = a * 2; // b is double a but a + b != n
```

or

```
int b = n - a; // sum is right and when a is a multiple of 3, b = 2 * a
```

In the second option

```
n = 6, a = 2, b = 4
n = 7, a = 3, b = 4
n = 8, a = 3, b = 5,
n = 9, a = 3, b = 6
n =10, a = 4, b = 6
n =11, a = 4, b = 7
n =12, a = 4, b = 8
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (n % 3 != 0) {
    n = ((n / 3) + 1) * 3;
}

int a = n / 3;
int b = a * 2;
```